# mysql inner join statement error

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I am getting the following error:

> 1052 - Column 'product_id' in field list is ambiguous

When I run the following:

```
SELECT `product_id`, `product_name`
FROM `products`
INNER JOIN `products_has_product_category`
   ON `products.product_id` = `products_has_product_category.product_id`
   AND `products_has_product_category.category_id` = 1
ORDER BY `products.product_name`
```

My `PRODUCTS` table has

```
product_id, product_name, etc
```

My `products_has_product_category` table has

```
product_id, category_id
```

This is my first try at a join, so I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify which table the `product_id` comes from. Since the `product_id` is in both tables, when you `SELECT` it you need to specify which table you want the value from. With a table alias:

```
SELECT p.product_id, p.product_name
FROM `products` p
INNER JOIN `products_has_product_category` pc
    ON p.product_id = pc.product_id
    AND pc.category_id = 1
ORDER BY p.product_name
```

Without table aliases:

```
SELECT `products`.`product_id`, `products`.`product_name`
FROM `products`
INNER JOIN `products_has_product_category`
  ON `products.product_id` = `products_has_product_category.product_id`
  AND `products_has_product_category.category_id` = 1
ORDER BY `products.product_name`
```

Comment: Thank you, that results are exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your intention correctly, you probably meant WHERE rather than AND:

```
SELECT `products`.`product_id`, `products`.`product_name`
          FROM `products`
          INNER JOIN `products_has_product_category`
          ON `products.product_id` = `products_has_product_category.product_id`
          WHERE `products_has_product_category.category_id` = 1
          ORDER BY `products.product_name`
```

Comment: Let me rephrase that - WHERE instead of AND.  Joins are performed on relationships between 2 tables, not between a value and a column in a table.  Where clauses are used for the latter situation.

Comment: Sorry, I miss understood what you had said, but bluefeet's answer is what I was looking for.  I did test your answer, and I still got the 1052 - Column 'product_id' in field list is ambiguous error.